# Access Ubuntu Host Files from RHEL installed on Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, shared-folders, redhat-enterprise-linux

Im trying to access Host files (Destop Folder) from RHEL installed on Virtual Box.

1. First I Shared a folder from menu bar of VirtualBox.
2. Then I make a directory in **/Media/ubuntushare**
3. Then I tried to mount Destop folder of Host system in
   **/media/ubuntushare**

But it return error

> mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the virtualbox guest additions package on the host and then install guest additions on the guest.

First install the guest additions package on the Ubuntu host:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Then open virtualbox, boot into RHEL and follow these steps ([source](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)):

1. Install [DKMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support), a framework that helps with building and upgrading kernel modules and the GNU C compiler (as root):

   ```
   yum install dkms
   yum install gcc
   ```
2. Mount the guest additions installation .iso (I have a windows guest but the VBox menus will be the same):

   [image]
3. Install guest additions (again as root):

   ```
   sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```
4. Modules are the linux equivalent of windows' drivers. The command below will load the necessary module (if it is not there) for mounting the shared folder (as root):

   ```
   modprobe vboxvfs
   ```
5. Try mounting the share now:

   mount -t vboxsf Desktop /media/ubuntushare

This, of course, assumes that you have [set up the share correctly](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders).

Comment: I dont know what ur suggested command do.

But actually i didn't installed Guest additions infact I tried it but I always run it VBoxLinuxAdditions.run without sh. 

And please suggest how to install Guest additions on Host there is no such option.

Comment: @UmairMustafa, see my updated answer.